# zsh profile path is not reflected.. in terminal in Mac OS 11.2.3

Tags: macos, zsh

I have installed mysql, trying to set path.
but somehow it does not reflect.

Is not Mysql compatible for zsh by any chance?

```
%  brew list| grep mysql
mysql@5.7
```

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

```
% echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

```
% source ~/.bash_profile
```

then

```
% mysql --version 
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

Comment: `zsh: command not found: mysql` means you're using a zsh shell and not a bash shell. zsh will not look at your `~/.bash_profile` but your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile` instead. Also see [this manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html) for a full list of files zsh will check on startup.

Comment: @tentative : This is true, but the OP claimed to have explicitly **sourced** .bash_profile from the zsh, and while it is for sure odd and begging for problems to source .bash_profile from within zsh, and even more odd to "edit" these files using `echo`, it is not forbidden and, in this particular case, should have worked. Note also that the OP also "edited" his .zshrc in the same way.

Comment: @conny : I find your posting a bit chaotic, in that we don't see exactly what's going on. For a more systematic approach, instead of firing wildly with `echo` at your files (we usually use a _text editor_ to edit a file), verify first at the point of your `mysql` invocation, whether the PATH is correct or not. If it is not, and you think that your dot files are set up correctly, you can debug them - for instance by creating a new shell with `zsh -x -l -i` and observe what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `zsh` in your terminal, so you need to add `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"` into your `~/.zshrc` file.

If you don't have that file, do `touch ~/.zshrc` then add that to your Zsh config file.

Alternatively, if you want to switch back to Bash, just do `chsh -s $(which bash)` (without `sudo` to only take effect on current logged-in user) and then restart your shell.

Comment: I tried this...

```
% echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```
But...
```
% mysql -v
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

Comment: You should run `source ~/.zshrc` so zsh loads that environment variable.

Comment: I tried source ~/.zshrc　but it dose not change at all.....

Comment: Maybe try restarting your terminal first if `source ~/.zshrc` don't work. @conny

Comment: I have tried restarting my terminal...but it didn't work.